# Python Lambda function variable ordering

Tags: python, lambda

If I state a lambda function like this:

```
someLambdaFunction = lambda x,y: x+x**2+y
```

can I reverse the ordering of that lambda to say

```
someOtherLambdaFunction = lambda y,x: x+x**2+y
```

without rewriting the whole lambda function? Just switch the arguments?

Comment: Well, you just did. All you had to do was switch the argument names, without rewriting the whole lambda function. Were you looking for something else?

Comment: @user2357112 they are looking for a function that can swap the argument positions of another function.

Comment: Why are you assigning lambdas to names? Both the camelcase and named lambdas are against PEP8

Comment: Forget PEP. There is almost never a reason to assign a `lambda` to anything.

Comment: Please stop harping on the lambda expression. There is no functional (pun intended) difference between a function defined by a `def` statement and a function defined by a lambda expression, and the choice to use a lambda expression here doesn't affect the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a general function that swaps the first two arguments of another function:

```
def swap2(func):
    """ Swap the first two arguments of a function """
    def wrapped(x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(y, x, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

f = lambda x,y: x+x**2+y
f_swapped= swap2(f)

assert f(3, 4) == f_swapped(4, 3)
```

This works because functions are just regular Python objects, that can be passed around just like integers, strings, etc.

By the way, there is almost never a reason to write `something = lambda ...`. Use `def something(...)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
someLambdaFunction = lambda x,y: x+x**2+y
someOtherLambdaFunction = lambda y, x: someLambdaFunction(x, y)
```

Basically, reuse the original `someLambdaFunction`

Comment: This does add a layer of indirection, though.

Comment: I don't get why you can't just call `someLambdaFunction(y, x)` directly?

Comment: @slider Probably only the OP knows the answer. Possibly, the lambda function acts as an argument of an existing interface?

Comment: @slider I'm trying to integrate a lambda function with multiple variables using quad and it only integrates over the first argument of the function.